# `req.session.user` is `undefined` when using `express-session` and `connect-mongo`

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express-session, connect-mongo

I've created a react app that runs on port:3000 and an express app that runs on port:3001.
I am using `express-session` and `connect-mongo` to handle user sessions. When I set a user session in `/login` it was recorded in MongoDB as expected. But when I query for `req.session.user` later in a different path/route, for example `/channels` it returns `undefined`.

This is how my `app.js` looks

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const {Server} = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const cors = require("cors");
const path = require('path');
const session = require('express-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');
const md5 = require('md5');
const hash = '=:>q(g,JhR`CK|acXbsDd*pR{/x7?~0o%?9|]AZW[p:VZ(hR%$A5ep ib.&BLo]g';

app.use(session({
    secret: hash,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    store: MongoStore.create({
        mongoUrl: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/chat',
        ttl: 14 * 24 * 60 * 60 // = 14 days. Default
    })
}));

app.use(
    cors({
        origin: true,
        credentials: true,
        optionsSuccessStatus: 200
    }));

// create application/json parser
const jsonParser = bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'})

// create application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser
const urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: false})

app.post('/login', jsonParser, (req, res) => {
    db.users.find({email: req.body.email}).toArray().then(user => {
        if (user.length < 1) {
            res.send({success: false, error: 'NOT_FOUND', message: 'Invalid login info!'});
        } else {
            user = user[0];
            if (user.password === req.body.password) {
                db.users.updateOne({"email": user.email}, {$set: {"online": "1"}}).then(ret => {
                    req.session.user = user.email;
                    req.session.userdata = user;
                    res.json(<=user data=>);
                });
            }
        }
    })
});

app.post('/channels', async (req, res) => {
    if (!req.session.user) {// THIS IS ALWAYS TRUE; EVEN AFTER SUCCESSFUL LOGIN
        res.json({logout: true});
        return;
    }
    const user = JSON.parse(req.session.userdata);
    const channels = db.channels.find({contacts: {$all: [user._id]}}).toArray().then(channels => {
        let allch = {};
        channels.map(function (channel) {
            channel.id = channel._id.toString();
            channel.notif = 0;
            allch[channel.id] = channel;
        });
        res.json(allch);
    });
});
```

Comment: How are you calling the Express server from your React app? Does it allow for cross-origin responses to set cookies?

Comment: Thanks, the problem was there. adding `credentials: 'include` in the request fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

When You fetch from front-end for specific route, don't forget to include in options: "credentials: "include" ", like here:

```
const options = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "content-type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(searchInput),
  credentials: "include",
};

fetch("http://localhost:4000/sendSearchInput", options)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Edit: 
Note - This should be included in each request from the client that either sets or reads the 'express-session' middleware (req.session.x).
(Not just reads)

Comment: NOTE: This needs to be applied to each request made which either SET or USE the session object. This is the solution to send requests across origins and use the 'express-session' middleware.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to call `req.session.save()` yourself when you want to update the session store with the current data.

Comment: `req.session.user = user.email;
 req.session.userdata = user;`  after these lines  in `/login` I added `req.session.save()`. Getting the same result.

Comment: Maybe you should use this instead https://github.com/jdesboeufs/connect-mongo

Comment: that's exactly what I am using

Comment: I am also facing this problem, pls what is the solution that work for you? @ShafayatAlam

Comment: @Paulliano adding ` credentials: "include",` in the front-end request fixed it for me

Comment: Okay thanks. I have already apply that but it still didnot work.